# Tensorflow, should i pay attention to error "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

Tags: tensorflow

Full error
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:112: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

I get it from simple model

```
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(len(X[0]),), dtype=tf.float32)
i = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, units//2, input_length=len(X[0]), activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4))(inp)#, mask_zero=True
i = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(units, activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4)))(i)
i = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4))(i)

model = tf.keras.Model(inp, i)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=1.), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is it something bad, do i really get things slower?